# How do I yank all matching lines into one buffer?

Tags: vim

How do you yank all matching lines into a buffer?

Given a file like:

```
match 1
skip
skip
match 2
match 3
skip
```

I want to be able issue a command to yank all lines that match a pattern (/^match/ for this example) into a single buffer so that I can put it into another doc, or into a summary or whatever.

The command should wind up with this in a buffer:

```
match 1
match 2
match 3
```

My first thought was to try:

```
:g/^match/y
```

But I just get the last match.  This makes sense, because the :g command is effectively repeating the `y` for each matching line.

Perhaps there is a way to append a yank to buffer, rather than overwriting it.  I couldn't find it.

Comment: I have been doing this sort of thing all day and find the solution to be less that I would like.  I do `qaq` followed by `:g/pattern/normal "AY` (didn't notice the :yank command before) then go to my buffer and paste it.  Is there no straight forward way to redirect directly into a buffer?  (Previously I'd been doing `:redir @a` `:g/pattern/` `:redir END`, so this is certainly a step in the right direction, but I just want one. more. step...)  :-)  I suppose I could write a function easily enough...

Comment: I have both upvoted this question because it was useful to me and voted to close it because that's the only way I see to say "this should be on superuser.com". It's a great question, but I think that's the correct place for it. Sorry that a "close" vote is the only way to vote to move.

Comment: @NathanLong, I believe this question predates superuser.  Probably should be migrated, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
:help registers
:help quote_alpha
```

Specify a capital letter as the register name in order to append to it, like `:yank A`.

Comment: This tip alone doesn't answer the question. Instead of `:g/^match/"Ay` (as alluded to) you need to do .e.g `:g/^match/normal "Ayy` or `:g/^match/yank A`.

Answer (score 165):

`:g/^match/yank A`

This runs the global command to yank any line that matches `^match` and put it in register `a`. Because `a` is uppercase, instead of just setting the register to the value, it will append to it. Since the global command run the command against all matching lines, as a result you will get all lines appended to each other.

What this means is that you probably want to reset the register to an empty string before starting: `:let @a=""` or `qaq` (i.e., recording an empty macro).

And naturally, you can use the same with any named register.

---

- [`:help registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers)
- [`:help quote_alpha`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_alpha)
- [`:help global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global)
- [Using Vi/Vim: Ex and Ex-like Commands](https://www.sbf5.com/%7Ecduan/technical/vi/vi-2.shtml)

Comment: What's implicit here is that one cannot append to the unnamed buffer, at least not in a single command.

You may also need to clear the buffer first:

    :let @a=""

Comment: Just a tip if you optimize for key strokes. Clearing register can be done quicker, by recording empty macro qaq.

Comment: @J.A.Faucett unnamed *register*, not buffer. Also, you kind of can do it ([based on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18536633/210945)): `:%g/regexp/let @"=@".getline('.')`. It joins lines together, although there may be a way around that.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering - run `:h multi-repeat` to see docs for the `:g` command

Answer (score 15):

Oh I just realized after commenting above that it's easy to yank matching lines into a temporary buffer...

`:r !grep "pattern" file.txt`

The simplest solutions come once you've given up on finding them.  :)

Comment: `:call setreg('a', system('grep "pattern" file.txt'))` or simply `:let @a=system('grep "pattern" file.txt')` if you want it in a register.

Comment: A more general solution can use `expand('%')` for the current buffer's filename, e.g. `:let @a=system('grep "pattern" '.expand('%'))`