# Vim: when matching a string across multiple lines using \_. in regex, the :yank command only works for the first line

Tags: regex, vim

I want to extract multiple occurences of some text that spans multiple lines and can be matched with a single Vim regex (using meta character `\_`).
Unfortunately, althouth the matching lines are properly highlighted in Vim,
when I add any Vim command (like delete or yank) after the matching regexp,
the command only works on the first line of each match.

**Example:**

```
 1: bad_function(arg1,  
 2:              arg2, arg3,
 3:              ...
 4:              argN);
 5: good_function();
 6: ...
 7: bad_function(arg2_1,
 8:              ...
 9:              arg2_N);
10: another_good_function();
```

If I execute `:g/bad_function([^;]\+\_[^;]\+;$/d`, then only lines
1 and 7 get deleted although highlighted are lines 1-4 and 7-9.

How to yank/delete all the matched (highlighted) lines?

Comment: Related maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474966/how-do-i-yank-all-matching-lines-into-one-buffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
:let @a=''
:g/first\_.*second.*$/normal! v/second^M$"Ay
```

Enter the `^M` with CTRL-V then Enter.

Comment: That seems a bit convoluted, why not just `:%g/first.*\|second.*/yank z`?

Comment: because this will not yank intermediate lines.

Comment: Indeed; the initial intent of the OP was not very clear and I see that the question has been since then modified to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accumulate matching ranges of lines in a register, one can use the
following command.

```
:let @a='' | g/^first/,/^second/y A
```

Comment: If that's the case, why does my `:%g/first\_.*second.*$/'<,'>y` work?

Comment: @Chris It works because you explicitly specify the line range to yank (which, by the way, equals to the range of the match only coincidentally—see my comment to your answer).

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in my comment; the linked question has the solution to your problem:

```
:%g/your_pattern/yank A
P
```

works for me.

If you want to match multiple terms on *different* lines, you can try (in command mode):

```
"zyy (do this on empty line to empty the register 'z')
:%g/first.*\|second.*/yank z (grab matches in the 'z' register)
P (for pasting the contents of the last register)
```

Comment: it still not work, only the first line yanked.I added an example above.

Comment: but if there are some lines that have no specific pattern between first and second line, how can you yank them?

Comment: @tombkeeper: I see that you have modified the e.g. posted in your question since it wasn't very clear with the way you had worded it previously.