# Delete lines with highlighted text / delete highlighted text

Tags: vim, highlighting

Does anyone know how to delete:

1. lines with highlighted text
2. all highlighted text self

(highlighted text (p.e. after a search) not selected text)

---

Is there a command which search all highlighted text and delete the line?
(independent which search command or function I used to highlight text)

the `g/pattern/d` command does not always delete the highlighted text
p.e. `/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$`    --> highlight all double lines
but `g/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/d`  --> does NOT delete all double lines

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you can delete the searched pattern this way:

```
:%s/<pattern>//gc
```

And you can delete the whole line with the searched pattern this way:

```
:g/<pattern>/d
```

Comment: Thank you remembering me how easy is it to delete lines with highlighted text but what do I have to do when text is highlighted after having used a function (p.e. in my menu) and I want to delete all lines with highlighted text?

Comment: @Remonn After a search when results are highlighted, you can use the last search pattern register `"/`.  Using @sixfeetsix solutions type `Ctrl`+`R`,`/` in place of `<pattern>`, and Vim insert the last search pattern.  This way you don't need to retype the whole pattern again and again.

Comment: Yes, I've found the same solution. Thank you for replying :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [sixfeetsix' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107303/vim-delete-lines-with-highlighted-text-delete-highlighted-text/6107405#6107405):

- to delete all lines NOT containing `<pattern>`, type `:g!/<pattern>/d` or `:v/<pattern>/g`
- to avoid having to type `<pattern>` after `:g/`, type `:g/`<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>`//d` which inserts the content of the search register (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>`/` means register `/`) into your command being typed.

Comment: the search register is not the same as deleting the highlighted text. p.e. when I search double lines I use this command: ^\\(.*\\)\\(\n\1\\)\+$ This highlight both double lines. When I insert the highlighted text in the g command g/ctrl-r/d it deletes only one highlighted line and not both.

Answer (score 4):

From [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/867826/261550):

> You can use `gn` in version 7.4 onwards (and `gN` to go backwards). It replaces the `v//e` trick.
>
> > Search forward for the last used search pattern, like with `n`, and start Visual mode to select the match.
>
> See `:help gn` or [this Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

> **how to delete: 2) all highlighted text self**

You could use search-and-replace (substitute) to do this.

It is generally used like this:

```
:%s/your_search_here/your_replacement_here/gc
```

More specifically, replace your search results with nothing (to remove them):

```
:%s/your_search_here//gc
```

Omit the `c` at the end to replace all without confirmation.

Type `:help :s` for more info.

> **how to delete: 1) lines with highlighted text**

To delete whole lines, you could either do a substitute, and just match the whole line with a regular expression (`%s/^.*your_search_here.*\n//g`), or you could use the multiple repeats (multi-repeat) feature.

It is generally used like this:

```
:g/your_search_here/[cmd]
```

More specifically, combine it with the normal command you use to delete a line (`d`):

```
:g/your_search_here/d
```

Type `:help :g` for more info.

**Tips**:

An easy way to get your query right before doing your substitute is to do your search in command mode rather than the default mode.

Instead of:

```
/your_search_here
```

Type:

```
:/your_search_here
```

Then you can go to command mode (`:`), hit the up key to bring up your last search, and edit the line to convert it to a substitute.

Comment: the `g/pattern/d` command does not always delete the highlighted text      
p.e. `/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$`    --> highlight all double lines        
but `g/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+$/d`  --> does NOT delete all double lines

Comment: @Remonn: Substitute should, though, if you expand your search to match the entire contents of all desired lines (and the trailing newline).  See the top part of my answer for `1)`, where I mention substitute :)

Comment: subsitute does (but leaves an empty line).   Substitute also doesn't delete the whole line when there are only a few characters highlighted.  I would like to delete the whole line when something is highlighted, I can't find out how to do this.

Comment: @Remonn: Trust me, substitute does what you want, if you're using it right.  You must change your search to "hilight" (match) each whole line, and match the trailing newline(s) too.  Then when you replace, you will delete the whole line as well as the resulting empty line.  If you give me some example source text and search text, I'll show you how to get it to do what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the essentially the same question as this:
[Vim: when matching string across multiple lines using \_. in regex, yank command only works for the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4290435/1286717)

It looks like a bug in Vim.

Comment: Related: [How to print a multi-line match?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5144/467)